# Port is not working for Xampp server

Tags: xampp

I am trying to start my Xampp server but I am getting error that port is already used with PID  .  I am unable to start the server .  how can i change the port of the server .  Please suggest .

I am getting given below log :- 
Port 80 is already used with PID 80.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit the file "httpd.conf***

Yes you can change the port.

## Listen 12.34.56.78:80

Listen 80 **#change this to 8080**

ServerName localhost:80 **#change this to 8080**